# Using http basic authentication with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, authentication, http-headers

I need to contact a server to consume a HTTP service.

Trying to reach the service with the browser, using `https://example.com/service` I get the basic authentication dialog.

Changing the URL to `https://username:password@example.com/service` easily bypasses that.

Trying to do the same using Ajax always results in `401 Unauthorized` though:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://username:password@example.com/service',
    // rest repeats
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function(text) { alert('success'); },
    error: function (text) { alert('error') },
    complete: function(text) { alert('complete'); }
});
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/service',
    username: username,
    password: password,
    // snip repeat
});
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/service',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "
            + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    // snip repeat
});
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11960692/1730482.

Comment: @marklap I alredy checked that question, but i still got the 401 error

Comment: have you tried the solution I linked to? The second block in that solution specifically?

Comment: Are you sure you use correct credentials? Try debugging in developer console (F12 in chrome) and make sure the header gets sent

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. Seems like the solution above doesn't work for me. I'm getting 400 - Bad request

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with a similar scenario myself..
What did the trick was using jsonp (ugh):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:8443/v1/accounts",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic bHVpZ2lAZ21haWwuY29tOmFiYzEyMzQ1');
        }
    })
```